# Change download location programmatically when receiving file from bluetooth

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I try to write a program that connect to other devices via bluetooth. 
I followed the instruction in Developer.android.com to set up a bluetooth connection and whenever other devices send a file to my phone, I want my app has a right to decide the download location? Is that possible?
If it does, then how to register to the OS that my App will override the download location.

Thanks in advance,